# mongodbの重複データ削除方法

Tags: mongodb

version3.0.0以前ではデータが重複している場合は

```
db.foo.ensureIndex({ bar: 1, baz: 1 }, { unique: true, dropDups: true });
```

することで削除できていたのですが、3.0.0以降には削除できなくなってしまいました

3.0.0以降で重複するデータを削除する方法を探しています。

どなたかご教授いただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33364816 の答えから：

確かめるステップ：{ "bar": 1, "baz": 1 }のキーの重複ドキュメントの_idをリストする

```
db.foo.aggregate([
  { $group: { 
    _id: { "bar": "$bar", "baz": "$baz"}, 
    dups: { "$addToSet": "$_id" }, 
    count: { "$sum": 1 } 
  }}, 
  { $match: { 
    count: { "$gt": 1 }    // 重複データ
  }}
])
```

消去を実行するステップ：

```
db.foo.aggregate([
  { $group: { 
    _id: { "bar": "$bar", "baz": "$baz"}, 
    dups: { "$addToSet": "$_id" }, 
    count: { "$sum": 1 } 
  }}, 
  { $match: { 
    count: { "$gt": 1 }    // 重複データ
  }}
]).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.dups.shift();      // 一番目を抜く
    db.foo.remove({_id : {$in: doc.dups }});  // ２番目からのドキュメントを削除する
})
```